# Kendo UI grid lastupdated field

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Having more issues with Kendo and hoping someone here might be able to help me.

I have a working kendo Grid which has a popup template for edit which calls, via AJAX a method on a Controller and updates the row. All fine.

The last column on each row is a last updated field which is supposed to update to DateTime.Now on edit.

Now because it is using Kendo to go and save the data there is no Success method that I can find nd therefore I can't return the saved data in Json format (And therefore the dateTime is never edited according to the grid).

I can't find a working event to fire a javascript function which would update the column client side.

So I am a bit stuck.

Anyone able to help?

Edit: As requested here is the code.

The Kendo grid which shows my attempt at giving it a default value (Didn't work and I know why) and shows it is calling a pop up.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Where(x => x.OrgLevel == 0).First().DefinedFieldsList)
                          .Name("DefinedlevelsGrid")
                          .Columns(columns =>
                          {
                              columns.Bound(x => x.FieldName).Title("Name");
                              columns.Bound(x => x.FieldTypeText).Title("Type");
                              columns.Bound(x => x.isMandatory).Title("Mandatory");
                              columns.Bound(x => x.DefaultValue).Title("Default Value");
                              columns.Bound(x => x.UpdatedOn).Title("Updated");
                              columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); });
                          })
                          .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("_OrgDefinedFieldEdit"))
                          .Pageable()
                          .Sortable()
                          .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                              .Ajax()
                              .Model(model => 
                                  {
                                      model.Id(x => x.FieldId);
                                      model.Field(x => x.UpdatedOn).DefaultValue(DateTime.Now.ToString());
                                  })
                              .Update(update => update.Action("EditDefinedField", "OrganisationAjax"))
                              .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Destroy", "Home"))
                          )
                    )
```

This is the Template view. I tried putting in a hidden field for the last updated field but didn't pursue that:

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI;

<div id="popupContainer">
<h2>Organisation Defined Field</h2>

<table id="PopupEditTable">
    <tr>
        <td>Name: </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.FieldName)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UpdatedOn)
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Type:</td>
        <td>
            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
            .Name("FieldTypeText")
            .DataValueField("Id")
            .DataTextField("Type")
            .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["FieldTypes"])
            )
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Description:</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Description)</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Mandatory:</td>
        <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.isMandatory)</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Default Value:</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.DefaultValue)</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i might be able to help, but i'm more a code oriented person, can you post the update method?

Comment: Just as a short sideline question, is the UpdatedOn field updated on the server side when you make changes, or you wish to keep this info only on client side?

Comment: Client side I think. I am not returning any data on the serverside request